# Parsing Modbus packets in pcap file using Scapy

Tags: python, scapy, modbus

I am new to Scapy. I am trying to parse Modbus packets in a pcap file using scapy.contrib.modbus. I am however successful. I want to at least identify request and response packets based on the library.
Below is the link for the pcap file:

https://github.com/tjcruz-dei/ICS_PCAPS/releases/download/MODBUSTCP%231/captures1.zip

Below is the sample code (doesn't work by the way):

```py
from scapy.all import *
import scapy.contrib.modbus as mb

    for pkt in PcapReader("captures1/clean/eth2dump-clean-0,5h_1.pcap"):
        if pkt['TCP'].sport == 502:
            pkt = mb.ModbusADUResponse(pkt)
        print(type(pkt))
```

Kindly assist. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code is actually much simpler than you think:

```py
import scapy.all as scapy
import scapy.contrib.modbus as mb

for pkt in scapy.PcapReader("eth2dump-clean-0,5h_1.pcap"):
    if mb.ModbusADUResponse in pkt:
        pkt.show()
```

let's got the detail of why/how it works.
scapy has a few relationship between protocol to help decode.

in you case: https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/contrib/modbus.py#L948
is linking TCP.port 502 to ModbusADUResponse